# Canada - Is a business or website a depreciable property

Tags: canada, canada-revenue-agency, depreciation

I'm considering buying a small online business. Is it a depreciable asset, and what [class](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/sole-proprietorships-partnerships/report-business-income-expenses/claiming-capital-cost-allowance/classes-depreciable-property.html) of asset?

Answer (score 3):

No. A business may *have* depreciable assets but is not itself a depreciable asset. A business is an investment.